# Is it possible to write a formula for this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, mathematical-modeling

Hi I have been struggling to write an equation/formula for a few hours. This is not a school or work assignment it is just for fun. Any help would be appreciated.

In this situation, two values, score and time, are used to calculate a final score

I have 3 sets of examples:

slow = ( [score:1354, time: 145], [score:460, time:31] )

medium = ( [score: 958, time: 35.6], [score: 329, time:11] )

fast = ( [score: 603, time: 22.4], [score: 212, time: 8] )

the indices of slow, medium, and fast, all represent a respective end-point in my game. So the first pair in each set all end at the same place but they reached there in different times, and due to a problem, there scores are different. I want it so that the extra time they took is accounted for and penalizes them. So for the first pair of each set, I want it to produce a final score that is highest for the lowest time. This equation should also produce the same result for the second pair of each set; since those also all end at the same respective location. I also would like it if the values stayed positive.

For example, for the first pair in each set if they had scores of

slow = 100

medium = 200

fast = 300

that would be great, and it would work if the same equation on the second pair in each set created:

slow = 10

medium = 20

fast = 30

so far I have tried stuff like this. I don't have a math education so I'm thinking it needs to be exponential, right?:

final score = score - time^(time*.009999)

Could anyone let me know if this is possible? Thank you

Comment: Based on these groupings it looks to me like you want score divided by time? (It would be a little safer to take $\frac{\text{score}}{\text{time} + 1}$ in case someone somehow gets a very very low time.

Comment: that definitely produces good looking results. Is there any way to also make the final score go down more as time increases?

Comment: How much faster do you want the score to go down? You could do something like $\frac{\text{score}}{1 + \text{time} + C \text{ time}^2}$ where $C > 0$ is an adjustable parameter; the bigger $C$ is the faster the score will go down. You could also make an adjustment that only starts kicking in after a certain time. Various other things are possible, it just depends on what you want.

Comment: I just realized that for the sets, it is granting higher final scores for the second pairs, which are supposed to have lower final scores, so this unfortunately does not work and makes me wonder if there is anything possible.